# My Nexus 4 always recognised as ADB device instead of MTP

Tags: nexus-4, usb-connection-mode

I plugged in Nexus 4 to my windows machine(XP Service Pack 2) and it didnt recognise or install any software automatically. I downloaded some ADB drivers from google and now it shows up as recognised device(that is ADB device) in the Device Manager, but it is not recognized as MTP . because of this i am not able to tranfer data into my phone or vice versa...

Comment: > Settings > Wireless & Network > USB utilities

From here you should be able to change to MTP.

Comment: You can also transfer files in ADB mode -- see e.g. [QtADB](http://qtadb.wordpress.com/) :)

Answer (score -2):

Uninstall the device from Device Manager, then plug it out and in again :)

Comment: What *Device Manager?* If you're referring to Windows's add/remove hardware tab page on the System Properties dialog box, then I suggest you re-edit your answer to include more information as its currently lacking details.